# getting Killed message in Python -- Is memory the issue?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a **`list`** which I **`.append()`** to in a **`for`**-loop, finally the length of the `list` is around 180,000. Each item in the `list` is a **`numpy`** array of 7680 **`float32`** values.

Then I convert the list to a `numpy` array, i.e. I expect an array of shape ( 180000, 7680 ):

```
d = numpy.asarray( dlist, dtype = 'float32' )
```

That caused the script to crash with the message Killed.

**Is memory the problem?** Assuming `float32` takes 4 bytes, 180000x7680x4bytes = 5.5 GB.

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu, 12 GB RAM.

Comment: Is your python 64 bit?

Comment: What are your `ulimit` settings?

Comment: I decided to work around this by declaring an array of shape (180000,7680) and assigning the data to it. (Was using list appending due to some legacy issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, memory is the problem

Your estimate also needs to take into account a memory-allocation already done for the **`list`**-representation of the `180000 x 7680 x float32`, so without other details on dynamic memory-releases / garbage-collections, the **`numpy.asarray()`** method needs a bit more than just another space of `1800000 x 7680 x numpy.float32` bytes.

If you try to test with less than a third length of the **`list`**, you may inspect the resulting effective-overhead of the **`numpy.array`** data-representation, so as to have exact data for your memory-feasible design

Memory-profiling may help to point out the bottleneck and understand the code requirements, that may sometimes help to save half of the allocation space needed for data, compared to an original mode of data-flow and operations:
[image: scikit-learn matrix allocations in numpy-based or BLAS-direct calling method]
(*Fig.*: Courtesy scikit-learn testing `numpy`-based or `BLAS`-direct calling method impact on memory-allocation envelopes )

Comment: So, uh... what exactly is the solution to the problem?

Comment: Welcome, @ShanerM13 - the original 2014 solution was (a) analytic step: downscale the problem to about 1/3 size & profile the actual memory I/O during the list-2-numpy.array conversion to see the blocking part + (b) design step: prevent blocking part by pre-allocating the target data storage ( a know size numpy.array instance ) and completely avoid the interim list-based phase ( having zero benefits over numpy.array + causing the blocker during the final conversion ) Anyway, P.F. 2022 !

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account, that you need twice the size of memory in the process of conversion.

Also, other software may take some of your RAM and when you have no additional paging space defined, using 11GB of your 12GB memory will probably bring your system into trouble.